# Experiencing limit in number of UILabels added as subviews

Tags: swift, uikit, swift-playground

Unable to add more than three UILabels to a UIViewController’s view in the IPad Playgrounds app. Is it me or the system?

Simplified code to show the issue. Hardware is a 2018 iPad Pro running iOS 12.3.1 Playgrounds app 3.0. Using UIViews up to five can be added successfully.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    let square50 = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var myFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: square50)
        for index in 0...4 {
            view.addSubview(UIView(frame: myFrame)) // fails at 6th!
            (view.subviews[index] as! UIView).backgroundColor = .red
            myFrame.origin.y += 80
        }
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

With the index range set as shown the code worked as expected, displaying the set number of coloured rectangles. With the range increased to 0...5 the runtime stopped with the message “There was a problem encountered while running this playground. Check your code for mistakes”.

Comment: Does `texts` have 4 items in it?

Comment: Yes it does and an “index out of range” runtime error occurs if not enough entries in the array.

Comment: If you create a tiny Playground program to test the subView limit by just adding empty UIView rectangles the code will fail at the sixth attempt to add the sub view.

Comment: Could you post that code? Stackoverflow recommends posting minimum reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How do I “post” the twenty lines of code? Sorry! I’ve done this on the Apple developer forum but all I can do here is add a limited comment!

Comment: You can edit your original post.

Comment: OK Craig, here’s the code!

Answer (score 1):

Just been able to test the code on Xcode 10.3 under OS X 10.16.6 on my iMac Retina 5k 27" late 2015. There is NO problem with the code and there is no short-range limit on the number of sub-views that can be created.

The problem rests with iOS Swift Playgrounds 3.0 running on an iPad Pro 12.9 inch 3rd-gen using iOS 12.3.1. This is therefore a bug!